# Best web-programming language for math-problems generator

Tags: php, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Firstly I am new in web programming but have knowledge in Java,C++, and HTML
I have a project for my college, in which I'll be making some sort of math-problems generator using web-programming language. It is something like www.wamap.org or basically it generates math problems based on the data stored in the database, generates the solutions, and compare them with students' solution. 
What would be the best language to use? I mean the one that is more convenient if I have experience in desktop programming. I am thinking of PHP right now, but a friend said Ruby on Rails would also make a great choice. I read a little bit about rails and I think it is more suitable for view-oriented web application which in this case is not my project. Any suggestions are really appreciated.

Regards,

Denny Harijanto

Comment: python FTW ;) ..I used it for numeric calculation course.. Very powerful!!

Comment: well... there's MathML. The rest depends on the toolkit you want to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby is a powerful language and could certainly be used to solve your problem. While I'm a fan of it that doesn't necessarily make it a great fit

The Rails framework is an excellent guide to writing well structured web apps based around a [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) model, typically backed by some form of SQL database. To my uninformed understanding of your problem this sounds like a good match for what you want to do. There's nothing I consider particularly "view oriented" about a Rails app compared to any other web application. For example I would still suggest Rails for a project which only intends to expose a RESTfull API and does not serve any html pages.

Comment: As a matter of fact, almost 5 years later and Rails 5 has support for building the application **solely** as [API](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you know java you can use Java servlets. It's very easy to implement (well, it's java).

Comment: Hahaha!! Wait, you're not kidding?